# Disable selected drop down option angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

TS FILE

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';


/**
 * @title Basic select
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'select-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-overview-example.css'],
})


export class SelectOverviewExample {
  resData = {
    "data": ["Pune", "Mumbai", "Pimpari", "Nagpur", "Hydrabad", "Assam", "Karnataka", "Bihar", "Maharashtra", "Delhi", "Srinagar", "Shimla", "Goa",  "Rajasthan", "MP", "Aandhra-Pradesh"]
  }
  selectOne : string ='';
  selectTwo='';
  selectThree='';
  selectFour='';
  one='';

   @ViewChild('select2') _select2: any
   firstSelections: string = '';

//    setFirstValues(form) {
//      this.firstSelections = form.value.select1
//      if (this._select2.value) {
//        const secondSelectionsValues = this._select2.value.slice();
//        for (var i = secondSelectionsValues.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
//          if (this.firstSelections.includes(secondSelectionsValues[i])) {
//              secondSelectionsValues.splice(i, 1)
//            this._select2.writeValue(secondSelectionsValues);
//          }
//        }
// }
// }


onChanged(){
  this.resData.data.forEach(ele =>{
if(ele == this.selectOne)
this.selectTwo !== this.selectOne;
  })
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">


  <div class="col-md-4">
<mat-form-field >
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectOne" name="selectOne" (selectionChange)="onChanged()">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let time1 of resData.data" value="time1" >{{time1}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
  </div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <mat-form-field >
        <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectTwo"  name="selectTwo"  (selectionChange)="onChanged()">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let time2 of resData.data" value="time2"  >{{time2}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select  [(ngModel)]="selectThree" name="selectThree">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let time3 of resData.data" value="time3" >{{time3}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectFour" name="selectFour">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let time4 of resData.data" value="time4" >{{time4}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
<form>
```

Explanation: when I select First drop down that value get disabled in drop down two , three and four! for every drop down that must me a unique value. value should not be same in every drop down!
is there any use of (selectionchange) or (ngModelChange)  events?
thanks in advance

here it is my stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/on-change-selection?file=app%2Fselect-overview-example.html

Comment: You can do one thing you are using array right so put one extra param slected flag for every data, if it is true then don't show it in the dropdown

Comment: @Aarsh How? demo please?

Comment: you can use multiple dropdown selection instead of using 4 different dropdown i don't know what the cause of using like this

Comment: @chethu could you please give me an stack-blitz demo?

Comment: some like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/on-change-selection-tnnshg

Comment: agreed but this was not the requirement Chethu sir! each drop down contain its value! that why i didn't make it as multiple !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a pipe that filters already selected data.

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'cityFilter',
  pure: false
})
export class CityFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], selectedItems: any[]): any {
    return items.filter(item => selectedItems.indexOf(item) < 0);
  }
}
```

And then use it in `*ngFor`

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectOne" name="selectOne">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let time1 of resData.data" [value]="time1">{{time1}}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectTwo" name="selectTwo">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let time2 of resData.data | cityFilter:[selectOne]" [value]="time2">{{time2}}         </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectThree" name="selectThree">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let time3 of resData.data | cityFilter:[selectOne,selectTwo]" [value]="time3">{{time3}}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectFour" name="selectFour">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let time4 of resData.data| cityFilter:[selectOne,selectTwo, selectThree]" [value]="time4">{{time4}}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
<form>
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/on-change-selection-yb4tgq

Comment: is there any way rather than doing Pipe? btw Thanks sir!

Answer (score 4):

In HTML ::

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">


  <div class="col-md-4">
<mat-form-field >
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectOne" name="selectOne" (selectionChange)="onChanged(selectOne)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let time1 of resData.data" [value]="time1" >{{time1}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
  </div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <mat-form-field >
        <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectTwo"  name="selectTwo"  (selectionChange)="onChanged(selectTwo)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let time2 of resData.data" [value]="time2"  >{{time2}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select  [(ngModel)]="selectThree" name="selectThree">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let time3 of resData.data" [value]="time3" >{{time3}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectFour" name="selectFour">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let time4 of resData.data" [value]="time4" >{{time4}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
<form>
```

In TS on change event ::

```
onChanged(event){
  console.log(this.resData.data[0]);
this.resData.data = this.resData.data.filter(ele => ele !== event);
console.log(this.resData);
}
```

Hope this will work for you !

Comment: This doesn't take care of the cascading condition though, and handling it in the onChanged event can get messy.

Comment: the data is dynamic so i cant put there selected value as false!

Comment: @Aarsh could you do it without changing my data bcz i cant add selected:false!

Comment: @CornelC could you please do this using onchange event withoud changing my data!

Comment: I change the answer as you asked for @JustTeachMe

Comment: @Aarsh if you dont mind could you please provide me a stackblitz demo?